# Magento 2 - Minified JS/CSS not generated in pub/static

Tags: magento2, minify

When enabling minify js and minify css within admin my storefront breaks. The markup is trying to call the minified files however these are not generated causing a lot of not found errors in browser console.

The store is in production mode and I have tried deploying static content and flushing all caches.

This is only an issue on the second store front however and the other seems to work perfectly with all js / css merged and minified correctly and generated within pub/static. For the second store front only non minified files seem to be present.

Comment: Is your store in Production mode.

Comment: Yeah store is set to production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following these steps in the following order fixed the issue for me:

**1.** Run Setup Upgrade

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

**2.** Run Compilation

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

**3.** Deploy static content

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB